# How to clear Numeric field by Jquery in Razor View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have model with `double` type field and `string` as well.

```
    [Display(Name = "Amount", ResourceType = (typeof(Resources.Work)))]
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "AmountInWords", ResourceType = (typeof(Resources.Work)))]
    public string AmountInWords{ get; set; }
```

After ajax call i am clearing the fields before submit even it is not mandatory property but it always showing `Amount Field is Required` event no `Required` attribute.

**Razor View:**

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "number"} })
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.AmountInWords, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

**Script**

```
$("#Amount").val('');
$("#AmountInWords").val('');
```

Comment: You need to make the underlying type nullable `double?`.

Comment: Can you share your View code and the ajax call code that you mentioned?

Comment: if it is not required make it nullable.

Comment: @Jasen so without `nullable` it cannot be solve?

Comment: You can't bind the empty form values to non-nullable property. If the property can't be nullable why are you posting blank values?

Comment: @Jasen becuase i have form that contain field acuiqing list of value for the save field. like sub-from posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in model used nullable variable : `double?`

```
  [Display(Name = "Amount", ResourceType = (typeof(Resources.Work)))]
    public double? Amount { get; set; }
```

or:

```
@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); } 
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "number"} })
```

Comment: Then have to change whole project to get Value of amount. It breaking change. Do you have other solution?

Comment: You don't have another solution, If you want to send without validation.

Comment: I already sending without validation. Did you check no volition on field.

Comment: try this: `@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "number"} })`